# Having Issues Mocking "marshalSendandReceive" method call in Mockito

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, mockito

I'm trying to create some unit tests in Mockito, and mocking a WebServiceTemplate call that returns a JAXBElement. I continually run into a NullPointerException, along with internal Mockito errors. How do I successfully mock the method call in Mockito?

I've researched a few other problems in StackOverflow, and while some of the problems are similar, none of them have provided a successful mock and test. My tests continues to fail.

Here is the method call in my actual code, within the SearchInvoker.class.

```
JAXBElement<SearchResponse> response = null;
JAXBElement<SearchRequest> req = soapClient.genConn(searchReq);

try {
    response = (JAXBElement<SearchResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate().marshalSendAndReceive(req, new SoapActionCallback("search"));
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    throw new Exception(e);
}
```

Here is how I'm trying to mock the call.

```
public class SearchInvokerTest extends PackageTest{

    @InjectMocks private SearchInvoker invoker;

    @Mock private SearchSoapClient soapClient;
    @Mock private WebServiceOperations template;

    @Test
    public void searchInvokerTest() throws Exception {
        ObjectFactory factory = new ObjectFactory();

        doReturn(factory.createSearchResponse(generateAwsSearchRsp())).when(template.marshalSendAndReceive(any(JAXBElement.class), any(WebServiceMessageCallback.class)));

        SearchResponse rsp = invoker.doSearch(new SearchRequestDVO());

        assertNotNull(rsp);
        assertEquals("123", rsp.getTraceID());
    }
}
```

Where I have my "when" and "doReturn" statement, I have a NullPointer as well as internal errors from Mockito. I expect the mocked class to be able to be returned.

Here is the stack trace of the error when I run mvn test:

```
[ERROR] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 2, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.018 s <<< FAILURE! - in SearchInvokerTest
[ERROR] searchInvokerTest(SearchInvokerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.002 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at SearchInvokerTest.searchInvokerTest(SearchInvokerTest.java:33)

[ERROR] searchInvokerTest(SearchInvokerTest)  Time elapsed: 0.017 s  <<< ERROR!
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException:

Misplaced or misused argument matcher detected here:

-> at SearchInvokerTest.searchInvokerTest(SymcorSearchInvokerTest.java:33)
-> at SearchInvokerTest.searchInvokerTest(SymcorSearchInvokerTest.java:33)

You cannot use argument matchers outside of verification or stubbing.
Examples of correct usage of argument matchers:
    when(mock.get(anyInt())).thenReturn(null);
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someVoidMethod(anyObject());
    verify(mock).someMethod(contains("foo"))

This message may appear after an NullPointerException if the last matcher is returning an object
like any() but the stubbed method signature expect a primitive argument, in this case,
use primitive alternatives.
    when(mock.get(any())); // bad use, will raise NPE
    when(mock.get(anyInt())); // correct usage use

Also, this error might show up because you use argument matchers with methods that cannot be mocked.
Following methods *cannot* be stubbed/verified: final/private/equals()/hashCode().
Mocking methods declared on non-public parent classes is not supported.
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace.

Comment: I included the stack trace. Additionally, none of the actual arguments are primitive, and when I try to change it to any(), the method becomes ambiguous because there are multiple marshalSendAndReceive methods with various arguments.

Comment: Looks like your mocks are not initialized. Have you added `@RunWith(MockitoJRunner.class)` as class annotation? Does the problem persist if you initialize the mock explicitly(`@Mock private WebServiceOperations template = mock(WebServiceOperations.class);`)?

Comment: Another thing comping to mind is to replace `any(JAXBElement.class)` with `any(Object.class)` (this should take care of the ambiguity)

Comment: Hey this has solved my current issue, and I'm just trying to mock the uri within the call. I have an idea of how to do that, thanks for your help! Can't believe I missed the RunWith annotation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that your mocks are not initialized.

You have to tell JUnit to run with the Mockito runner:

```
[...]
@RunWith(MockitoJRunner.class)
public class SearchInvokerTest extends PackageTest {
    [...]
}
```

This will, among other things, initialize your mocks.

Comment: I'm still getting this issue after adding MockitoExtension.
@ExtendWith({SpringExtension.class, MockitoExtension.class})
when(webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(anyString(), any(EmailMessageRequest.class))).thenReturn(requestArgument.capture());